# Curl SSL & Connection Timeout Intermittently in Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

i think my problem is totally different than rest questions on Stackoverflow. I searched and googled everywhere but dint find accurate solution or reason for it. Hope i get some information over here.

My facebook application using Facebook PHP SDK and my apps working fine most of the time. They do give sometime few errors in general. But now suddenly my facebook apps fails to fetch user data after authentication and take too much time to load, which was working totally fine previosly. This sudden change happen with every app, in between it do authenticate some users but in minor case. To see in error log, it throws error like:
**CurlException: 28: SSL connection timeout**
**CurlException: 28: Operation timed out after 60000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received**
**Uncaught CurlException: 28: SSL connection timeout** 
**CurlException: 28: connect() timed out!**
**CurlException: 7: couldn't connect to host**

But strange thing is, that this occur at any time but this sudden change automatically stop and all app start working fine and normal like previous after 5 - 8hrs. Now i am confused what may be making such problem? Is it Rate Limit from Facebook? I did nslookup, ping, curl -v, to api.facebook.com and it gives output too. Even my port and firewall rules are OK.
Please Help Me friends

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes network connections will fail.  Sometimes remote services will fail.  You can't think of a remote service call over HTTP over the internet into a 3rd party's systems as fail proof.  You must write your software to expect this & handle it gracefully.  Set reasonable timeouts, look for failures & be prepared to retry a few times before giving up.

Comment: But this occurs for some hours like example 5 to 6 hours and then all apps start working fine like always. Not even 1-10 errors. Am getting load of errors. Is there any Rate Limit ? During this i even did nslookup and it connects fine to facebook graph